# Can I allow anonymous and active directory users to browse the same IIS 7.5 site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, active-directory

I have a site through which the majority of users will be anonymous but a few will be active directory users.

I'd like to;

- Enable full anonymous access for everyone without logins.
- Detect the AD users.
- Check if the AD users are members of a specific admin group.

I'm using .Net 4.0, C# and IIS 7.5 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable anonymous access windows authentication will not happen. You can implement a [custom authentication provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) that calls AD and sets the anonymous user when authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AD login in asp.net so why not just hide AD content and allow the user to login to see the full view?